How to Display Duty and Tax Information Using Shopify Carrier Service API and Checkout Extension
I’ve successfully created a Carrier Service API and can listen to the callback on the checkout page. The API returns service_name, service_code, total_price, etc., and the UI displays the correct information from the callback. The total_price includes duty and tax amounts, so I need to use a checkout extension to show these details.
However, the callback does not return separate information for duty and tax. How can I display this information using the checkout extension?
